# How to get max amount of value in same key in array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, max

How to get max amount of value in same key in array

E.x

I have this array.

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [amount] => 4
)
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [amount] => 3
)
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [amount] => 3
)
```

**I want below result . means  i want max amount value for same id .please provide solution for same.**

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [amount] => 4
)
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [amount] => 3
)
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this any faster than O(n)..... so just loop through them.

Comment: Yeah, try something for yourself first - the only way to learn ;-)

Comment: but i want to remove less amount of id from array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $bigArray = [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'amount' => 4
        ],
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'amount' => 3
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
            'amount' => 3
        ]
    ];


    $output = [];

    foreach($bigArray as $innerArray){
        if(!isset($output[$innerArray['id']])){
            $output[$innerArray['id']] = $innerArray;
        }
        elseif( $output[$innerArray['id']]['amount'] < $innerArray['amount'] ){
            $output[$innerArray['id']] = $innerArray;
        }
    }

    print_r($output);
    exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort the array by the highest amount first, then just get the first result back. For example:

```
usort($theBigArray, function($a, $b) {
    return ($a['amount'] - $b['amount']);
});

print_r($theBigArray);
```

Comment: its not working please provide another solution for same