# PHP: Remove duplicate elements and get the latest data in the array

Tags: php, laravel

```
$arr = [
        [
            "id" => '6230061c0e88d709ca0d7bbc',
            'name' => 'Mobile SamSung',
            'slug' => 'mobile-samsung',
            'createdAt' => '1648006346'

        ],
        [
            "id" => '5d1eff529a426778d4b92383',
            'name' => 'Mobile Iphone',
            'slug' => 'mobile-iphone',
            'createdAt' => '1647314181'
        ],
        [
            "id" => '5d1eff6b9a426778d4b92dc4',
            'name' => 'Mobile SamSung',
            'slug' => 'mobile-samsung',
            'createdAt' => '1647314460'

        ],
        [
            "id" => '5f894011266aea580b028cb0',
            'name' => 'Mobile LG',
            'slug' => 'mobile-lg',
            'createdAt' => '1647314456'

        ]
    ];
```

I have an array, and in this array there are many duplicate subarrays, now I want to remove the duplicate arrays inside, keeping only the data with the latest `createdAt`. Please give me your opinion. Thanks

I would like to get an array like this:

```
$arr = [
            [
                "id" => '6230061c0e88d709ca0d7bbc',
                'name' => 'Mobile SamSung',
                'slug' => 'mobile-samsung',
                'createdAt' => '1648006346'

            ],
            [
                "id" => '5d1eff529a426778d4b92383',
                'name' => 'Mobile Iphone',
                'slug' => 'mobile-iphone',
                'createdAt' => '1647314181'
            ],
            [
                "id" => '5f894011266aea580b028cb0',
                'name' => 'Mobile LG',
                'slug' => 'mobile-lg',
                'createdAt' => '1647314456'

            ]
        ];
```

Comment: Seems like a simple `foreach` to construct a new array with an `if` on the createdAt. What have you tried so far? Show us your code and your attempt so we can help you improve your existing code.

Comment: @Andrea Olivato
  I'm really stuck. I use `foreach` loop and use `in_array` to check it. But still not working. Can you suggest me. I'm new to PHP really hard

Comment: Edit your question and show your code so far. Even if it doesn't work, show that you're trying something. As a hint, you can't use `in_array` because you need to check the `id` element. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @AndreaOlivato Are you sure the `id` is what needs to be checked? These seem to be different, but the `name` and `slug` are duplicates on the array. On those duplicates, the `createdAt` needs to be checked.

Comment: You're right, I've read too quickly, it's the slug as you mention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not make more than one pass over your data.  Just use the `name` values as temporary keys, then only retain a duplicate row's data if its `createAt` value is greater than what is stored.  Re-index the array when you are finished looping.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RTOrF))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['name']]) || (int)$row['createdAt'] > (int)$result[$row['name']]['createdAt']) {
        $result[$row['name']] = $row;
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '6230061c0e88d709ca0d7bbc',
    'name' => 'Mobile SamSung',
    'slug' => 'mobile-samsung',
    'createdAt' => '1648006346',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '5d1eff529a426778d4b92383',
    'name' => 'Mobile Iphone',
    'slug' => 'mobile-iphone',
    'createdAt' => '1647314181',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '5f894011266aea580b028cb0',
    'name' => 'Mobile LG',
    'slug' => 'mobile-lg',
    'createdAt' => '1647314456',
  ),
)
```

Potentially helpful:

- [Laravel - fetch unique rows from table having highest value in x column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64681921/2943403)
- [Remove duplicate objects from array based on one value, keep lowest of other value in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42281756/2943403)
- [Filter rows with unique column value and prioritize rows with a particular value in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70505888/2943403)
- [How to get max amount of value in same key in array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42976042/2943403)

Comment: The answer is perfect. My code worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

***Explanation:***

In this solution, I have gotten the data with a unique `slug` key with the latest `createdAt` key. we can have any unique key that matches into the multidimensional array and get the result whatever we want.

***Code:***

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $findIndex = array_search($value['slug'], array_column($newArray, 'slug'));
    if ($findIndex === false) {
        $newArray[] = $value;
    } elseif ($findIndex !== false && $newArray[$findIndex]['createdAt'] <= $value['createdAt']) {
        $newArray[$findIndex] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($newArray);
```

1. Demo Link (With your Data): https://3v4l.org/f4kRM
2. Demo Link (Customized Data with my way): https://3v4l.org/sj4MW

Answer (score 0):

First sort on created at, then remove duplicates.

```
<?php
$arr = [
        [
            "id" => '6230061c0e88d709ca0d7bbc',
            'name' => 'Mobile SamSung',
            'slug' => 'mobile-samsung',
            'createdAt' => '1648006346'

        ],
        [
            "id" => '5d1eff529a426778d4b92383',
            'name' => 'Mobile Iphone',
            'slug' => 'mobile-iphone',
            'createdAt' => '1647314181'
        ],
        [
            "id" => '5d1eff6b9a426778d4b92dc4',
            'name' => 'Mobile SamSung',
            'slug' => 'mobile-samsung',
            'createdAt' => '1647314460'

        ],
        [
            "id" => '5f894011266aea580b028cb0',
            'name' => 'Mobile LG',
            'slug' => 'mobile-lg',
            'createdAt' => '1647314456'

        ]
    ];
    
function sort_objects_by_created($a, $b) {
    if($a['createdAt'] == $b['createdAt']){ return 0 ; }
    return ($a['createdAt'] > $b['createdAt']) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Let's sort
usort($arr, 'sort_objects_by_created');

$slugs = [];
$result = [];

// Loop object
foreach($arr as $phone) {
    // If slug is not found, add to result
    if (!in_array($phone['slug'], $slugs)){
        $slugs[] = $phone['slug'];
        $result[] = $phone;
    }    
}    

var_dump($result,$slugs);
```

Comment: Thanks . error : `usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'sort_objects_by_created' not found or invalid function name`

Comment: This answer works https://3v4l.org/fKu84, BUT is not as efficient as it can/should be.  Making iterated `in_array()` calls is not something that I endorse in any professional projects.  Sorting the entire array on `createAt` is also more work than is necessary.  See my answer for the optimized approach.

Answer (score -1):

Might be worth a note, that you might be able to improve this upstream when creating your array. (always look upstream!)

If you can give you base array a key of created At you can use Array sorting, which which will this step more effecient....

E.g.

```
$arr = [];
$arr[2022-01-01] = Array('id' => 123, 'name' = 'abc');
$arr[2022-04-01] = Array('id' => 123, 'name' = 'abc');
$arr[2022-08-01] = Array('id' => 123, 'name' = 'abc');
```